# Crank-Nicolson solution of parabolic PDE with Newumann boundary conditions

Tags: pde, crank-nicolson

I am trying to solve the non-linear parabolic PDE in $c(t,r)$
$$c_t=\frac{1}{r}(rDc_r-\alpha r^2 c)_r$$
with initial  condition $c(0,r)=f(r)$
and boundary conditions $c_r(t,r_1)=\alpha r_1c_1/D$ and $c_r(t,r_n)=\alpha r_nc_n/D$; in other words, there is no flux across the boundaries.

This the Lamm equation, a 1-dimensional problem in cylindrical coordinates. In the simplest case, $D$ and $\alpha$ are constants.

I have set up a uniformly-spaced $r$ grid with $n$ points, so $r_j=r_1+(j-1)\Delta r$, with $1<=j<=J$. I'm using the Crank-Nicolson method with forward difference for $c_t$, and central differences for $c_{rr}$ and $c_r$. At the boundaries, I have added "ghost points" $c_0$ and $c_{J+1}$.

The difference equation resulting is, for $j=1,\ldots, J$
$$\frac{c_{n+1,j}-c_{n,j}}{\Delta t}=
\frac{D}{2}\left[\frac{c_{n,j+1}-2c_{n,j}+c_{n,j-1}}{(\Delta r)^2}+\frac{c_{n+1,j+1}-2c_{n+1,j}+c_{n+1,j-1}} {(\Delta r)^2}\right]
 +\left(\frac{D}{ 2r_j}- \frac{\alpha r_j}{ 2}\right) \left[\frac{c_{n,j+1}-c_{n,j-1}}{ 2\Delta r}
+\frac{c_{n+1,j+1}-c_{n+1,j-1}}{ 2\Delta r}\right]
 -\alpha\left[c_{n,j}+c_{n+1,j}\right]$$
where now $c_{n,j}$ is the value of $c$ at the radial point $j$ and the $n$-th time step. Values for the "ghost points" are obtained from the above equation applied at $j=1$ and $j=J$ and the boundary conditions. They are then substituted into the difference equation.

This formulation leads to the matrix equation ${\bf Fc}^{n+1}={\bf Gc}^n$, where ${\bf F}$ and ${\bf G}$ are tridiagonal, and ${\bf c}^k$ is a column vector of $c_{k,j}$ at time step $k$.

Solving for ${\bf c}^{n+1}$ gives a result that does not conserve mass (i e, $c$). Since the boundaries have 0 flux, $\int_{r_1}^{r_J} r dr$ should remain constant, but it does not.

Can anyone advise me if there is something I have done incorrectly, or where to look for an error in the computations? I did not include the elements of ${\bf F}$ and ${\bf G}$, but I could make those available.

Comment: I don't see the non-linearity in you equation.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that your discretization *should* preserve mass?

Comment: If the flux at both boundaries is zero, mass will be conserved. The PDE models experimental situations where mass cannot escape. But I admit the discretization could be incorrect.

Comment: I think that Wolfgang was referring to conservation of mass in the discretization and not in the original problem. In general, a discretization is not conservative even if some quantity was concerned in the continuous counterpart.

Comment: Numerical Recipes recommends Crank-Nicolson for diffusive IVP, so I believe a correct discretization will conserve mass. Is there a way to tell whether a particular discretization is conservative? And is my discretization correct?

Comment: That's probably a good question for a new post.